# Haskell combinations and permutation

Tags: haskell

I have three word in a list ["a","b","c"]. i want to find all possible combination in set 5,6 etc.

for example for set of 5 i would have

```
**[ [aaaaa],[aaaab],[aaaac], [aaabc] , ..... ]** etc 3 ^ 5 = 243 combinations
```

aaaaaa above will basically be "a","a","a","a","a" ....

Comment: i am working on this from yesterday. did not go much further. if i can get some idea then i might be able to do it.

Comment: @user1115751: To start, search for "[haskell cartesian product](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=haskell+cartesian+product&submit=search)".

Answer (score 21):

`replicateM` does what you want:

```
> import Control.Monad
> replicateM 5 ["a", "b", "c"]
[["a","a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a","b"],["a","a","a","a","c"],["a","a","a","b","a"],["a","a","a","b","b"],["a","a","a","b","c"],["a","a","a","c","a"],["a","a","a","c","b"],["a","a","a","c","c"],["a","a","b","a","a"],["a","a","b","a","b"],["a","a","b","a","c"],["a","a","b","b","a"],["a","a","b","b","b"],["a","a","b","b","c"]...]
```

Answer (score 21):

Of course, nanothief's answer gives the shortest solution, but it might be instructive and fun to do it yourself.

There are many ways to write a function for the cartesian product. E.g. you can use list comprehensions:

```
prod :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
prod as bs = [a ++ b | a <- as, b <- bs]
```

Where `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` -- see [Data.List](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/base-4.9.1.0/Data-List.html#v:-43--43-). Another possibility is to use the `Applicative` instance of list:

```
import Control.Applicative

prod as bs = (++) <$> as <*> bs
```

Now you need to apply this operation repeatedly. A fold can do this, e.g.:

```
rep :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
rep n as = foldr1 prod $ replicate n as

rep 3 ['a','b','c']
--["aaa","aab","aac","aba","abb","abc","aca","acb","acc","baa","bab",
--"bac","bba","bbb","bbc","bca","bcb","bcc","caa","cab","cac","cba",
--"cbb","cbc","cca","ccb","ccc"]
```

Understanding this solution might be more valuable than taking the `replicateM` short cut. That said, you could have found the latter easily using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D).

--

For more on Functors and Applicative see definitions [fmap](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/base-4.9.1.0/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) (`<$>`) and [ap](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/base-4.9.1.0/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) (`<*>`). [*Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures*](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) can also be a good resource.

Comment: This does not compile. There must be a type constraint for the operands passed to `++`

Comment: I tried this in GHCi, there it works without constraints.

Comment: How would you modify this for numbers, for example? Or any other type?

Comment: @dopatraman You don't need to modify anything, you just need to use lists, e.g. `rep 3 [[1],[2],[3]]`. Strings work as they are just `[Char]` in disguise. Of course you can also pass more interesting lists, like  `rep 3 [[1,2,3],[4,5]]`.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to treat the second argument as `[a]` instead if `[[a]]`. Using your setup I would not be able to do that because `(++)` cannot be called with a number.

Comment: Then you can use `rep n as = foldr1 prod $ replicate n (fmap (:[]) as)`, but this would limit your flexibility. Also it is not "my setup", it is the signature required to answer the original question, and the other answer has the same signature as well.