# All possible combinations of a list's elements

Tags: haskell

I need to get all possible combinations of a list's elements. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658409/haskell-combinations-and-permutation/9663864?noredirect=1#comment63023943_9663864) but it does not compile. Please help me figure this out:

```
subseq :: [a] -> [[a]]
subseq [] = []
subseq (x:xs) = map (x :) $ subseq xs
```

Basically this is a rewrite of the `subsequences` function in `Data.List`. I dont understand the version in the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#subsequences) though. My rationale behind the function above is this.

Apply the cons operator across all elements. This should produce a non deterministic result. However, the result I'm getting is an empty list. Please help.

Comment: Hint: if I map an operation over an empty list, how much less empty is the result?

Answer (score 6):

Let's start form the base case. The power set of the empty set is a set containing the empty set. So you need to replace `subseq [] = []` with `subseq [] = [[]]`. Right now you're saying that the powers of an empty set is empty, which is not the case.

Your other case is missing something too. You need to change it to `subseq (x:xs) = (subseq xs) ++ map (x :) (subseq xs)`. In plain english, this means that you take the subsets that don't contain the first item (`subseq xs`) and the subsets that contain it (`map (x :) (subseq xs)`).

If you omit the `(subseq xs)` part all you get is a list that contains only the original list because you only consider the sublist where you take every element.

Answer (score 0):

You may also achieve this task with `filterM :: Applicative m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]` function which resides in Control.Monad.
In this particular case our monad is list so we need a filtering function of type `(a -> m Bool)` which returns a list of boolean values. This could be `\x -> [True, False]` and the monad instance of list will apply them for each element of the provided list undeterministically and will result a list of lists.

```
Prelude> Control.Monad.filterM (\n -> [True, False]) [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```